# Ubuntu 22.04 LTS setup doesn't see hard drive (USB dual boot with Windows 11)

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, windows, 22.04, usb-installation

I have a Lenovo Yoga Slim 7 Pro 14 ACH5 with AMD Ryzen 7 and 1 TB SSD. It came with a pre-installed Windows 11 and I wanted to dual-boot Ubuntu, so I etched Ubuntu 22.04 LTS using Rufus (see config details in the notes in the end), and in 'try' mode it works fine.

When I try to install Ubuntu, it fails at around the same spot: either it arrives at the 'Installation type' windows and there is no partitions to select (if I click + or Change it freezes), or it stops the setup with:

> You need at least 8.6 GB disk space to install Ubuntu. This computer
> has only 8.1 GB.

[as shown here for the curious](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sjK46.png).

I shrinked the Windows partition to 300 GB, and tried to install both with unallocated and simple volume (exFAT).

So, I then tried to check if the only detected disk is the 8 GB USB, and confirmed that's the case:

> sudo lshw -class storage -class disk

```
  *-nvme UNCLAIMED                 description: Non-Volatile memory controller
       product: Gold P31 SSD
       vendor: SK hynix
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
       version: 00
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: nvme pm msi msix pciexpress nvm_express cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: memory:fd400000-fd403fff memory:fd405000-fd405fff memory:fd404000-fd404fff   *-usb:0
       description: Mass storage device
       product: UDisk
       vendor: General
       physical id: 2
       bus info: usb@1:2
       logical name: scsi0
       version: 1.00
       capabilities: usb-2.00 scsi emulated scsi-host
       configuration: driver=usb-storage maxpower=100mA speed=480Mbit/s
     *-disk
          description: SCSI Disk
          product: UDisk
          vendor: General
          physical id: 0.0.0
          bus info: scsi@0:0.0.0
          logical name: /dev/sda
          version: 5.00
          size: 7680MiB (8053MB)
          capabilities: removable
          configuration: ansiversion=2 logicalsectorsize=512 sectorsize=512
        *-medium
             physical id: 0
             logical name: /dev/sda
             size: 7680MiB (8053MB)
             capabilities: gpt-1.00 partitioned partitioned:gpt
             configuration: guid=8ca7622d-3925-4219-8bc1-816855d10f8b
```

> sudo fdisk -l

```
Disk /dev/loop0: 2.33 GiB, 2502324224 bytes, 4887352 sectors Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes       

Disk /dev/loop1: 4 KiB, 4096 bytes, 8 sectors Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop2: 61.89 MiB, 64901120 bytes, 126760 sectors Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop3: 155.63 MiB, 163188736 bytes, 318728 sectors Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop4: 248.76 MiB, 260841472 bytes, 509456 sectors Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop5: 284 KiB, 290816 bytes, 568 sectors Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop6: 45.86 MiB, 48087040 bytes, 93920 sectors Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes

Disk /dev/loop7: 43.63 MiB, 45748224 bytes, 89352 sectors Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/sda: 7.5 GiB, 8053063680 bytes, 15728640 sectors Disk model: UDisk            Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes Disklabel type: gpt Disk identifier: 8CA7622D-3925-4219-8BC1-816855D10F8B

Device     Start      End  Sectors  Size Type /dev/sda1   2048 15728606 15726559  7.5G Microsoft basic data

Disk /dev/loop8: 81.26 MiB, 85209088 bytes, 166424 sectors Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes root@ubuntu:/home/ubuntu#
```

Few more notes:

- Windows fast boot disabled
- secure boot (in BIOS) disabled
- Rufus configs I tried: Partition scheme MBR and GPT, Target system default (UEFI or BIOS), File system default (FAT32).
- I also tried Ubuntu 18, 20 and 22 with 3 different USB sticks, giving slightly different error, but in essence no hard disk was detected
- can't change RAID>AHCI because in UEFI there is no such option (this is frustrating on its own, didn't know Lenovo blocks access to these features now)
- Windows 11 has its own issues with frequent BDOS, but do not seem related to the hard disk
- updated UEFI to the latest version (the one downloaded from Lenovo was older than my ROM)

I'm kinda stuck except the idea to buy an external SSD and install it there. Thanks for any tips!

Comment: As usual and before anything else update UEFI. Then please read the full user's manual to familiarize yourself with the UEFI settings. If the drive mode currently is "RAID" or "Intel RST" and can't be changed to AHCI then the drive won't be detected, end of story.

Comment: Thanks, I edited the post to add: I also tried updating UEFI and only downgrade was available, and it's not Intel but AMD.

Comment: CPU has nothing to do with drive modes although AMD based ones typically don't have Intel RST but can have other equally not (yet) compatible. And again, nothing else to add.

Comment: @ChanganAuto, In a Dell Latitude 3520, I can use the default operating mode, "Raid On" with VMD controller. Windows continues to use RST and Lubuntu 22.04 LTS uses the kernel VMD driver (selected automatically). So with version 22.04, it is no longer necessary to switch to AHCI/NMVe mode (which is also available in the UEFI/BIOS system of this Dell). -- I have not checked which mode provides faster access for Linux (but assume that VMD/RST is faster for Windows).

Comment: @ChanganAuto, but in the computer of this thread there is AMD hardware, and you are *probably* right, that its corresponding Raid feature is not yet compatible with Linux (no driver for it).

Comment: If drive is NVMe type SSD, it also may need firmware update. Some Lenovo systems have extra UEFI security settings in addition to UEFI Secure Boot. As in first comment, best to review manual to see what UEFI/BIOS settings you have.